# (Wordpress) .htaccess Selective Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the home of my old site to the home of my new site, while I want every subpage to redirect to the page search of the new site.
Briefly:

**www.oldsite.it** --> **http://newsite.it**

*and*

**www.oldsite.it/whatever** --> **http://newsite.it/search?q=whatever**

I want the conditions to live both and strictly.
I achieved to let them work but separately. 
Here's my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite\.it/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.it/search?q=$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I make them work? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 conditional rules here to redirect the old homepage and old urls to the new location ,try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#1)redirect "oldsite.it" to "newsite.it#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.it$ 
RewriteRule ^$ http://newsite.it [NC,L,R]    
#2)redirect "oldsite.it/foobar" to "newsite.it/search?q=foobar#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.it$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://newsite.it/search?q=$1 [QSA,NC,R,L]
```

Clear your browser's cache before testing these rules.

To make the redirect permanent ,change R to R=301 in both rules when you are sure the rules are working.